# Validate JWT access_token from AAD Azure Fails

Tags: python, azure, jwt, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to validate a azure jwt access_token from the service I'm working on. We are currently making a request to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me. If the request succeeded, the token is valid. Unfortunately we will not be able to keep doing that.

I have tried a variety of ideas for this. None of them with success. Even jwt.io does not recognize the signature, even though jwt `kid` and the `kid` from one of the available signatures in [jwk_uri](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys) matches.

Based on this blog [post](http://ttps://aboutsimon.com/blog/2017/12/05/Azure-ActiveDirectory-JWT-Token-Validation-With-Python.html) I have created a following solution [(also available on github)](https://github.com/tmpapageorgiou/jwt-validation-tool) .

My implementation is very similar to the blog post with a few changes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import jwt
import requests
import sys

from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend


def get_public_key(access_token):
    """ Retrieve public key for access token """
    token_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(access_token)

    res = requests.get('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration')
    jwk_uri = res.json()['jwks_uri']

    res = requests.get(jwk_uri)
    jwk_keys = res.json()

    x5c = None
    # Iterate JWK keys and extract matching x5c chain
    for key in jwk_keys['keys']:
        if key['kid'] == token_header['kid']:
            x5c = key['x5c']
            break
    else:
        raise Exception('Certificate not found in {}'.format(jwk_uri))

    cert = ''.join([
        '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n',
        x5c[0],
        '\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n',
    ])
    try:
        public_key =  load_pem_x509_certificate(cert.encode(), default_backend()).public_key()
    except Exception as error:
        raise Exception('Failed to load public key:', error)

    return public_key, key['kid']

def main():
    print '\n'
    if len(sys.argv) < 2 or '-h' in sys.argv:
        print 'Run it again passing acces token:\n\tpython jwt_validation.py <access_token>'
        sys.exit(1)

    access_token = sys.argv[1]
    audience = 'https://graph.microsoft.com'

    public_key, kid = get_public_key(access_token)

    try:
        jwt.decode(
            access_token,
            public_key,
            algorithms='RS256',
            audience=audience,
        )
    except Exception as error:
        print 'key {} did not worked, error:'.format(kid), error
        sys.exit(1)

    print('Key worked!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This solution returns `Invalid Signature` for a valid access_token with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "jwt_validation/jwt_validation.py", line 63, in <module>
    main()
File "jwt_validation/jwt_validation.py", line 57, in main 
    audience=audience,
File "~/.pyenv/versions/jwt-validation-tool/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 93, in decode
    jwt, key=key, algorithms=algorithms, options=options, **kwargs
File "~/.pyenv/versions/jwt-validation-tool/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 157, in decode
    key, algorithms)
File "~/.pyenv/versions/jwt-validation-tool/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 224, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidSignatureError('Signature verification failed')
jwt.exceptions.InvalidSignatureError: Signature verification failed
```

Any ideas of what I could be wrong would be helpful.

Comment: Could you include the error message here as well? In `jwt` documentation, they expect the `algorithms` value as a list. Not sure if thats the issue here.

Comment: Thanks @RakihthaRR for the suggestion. Traceback added.
The value algorithms='RS256' can be a list as you mention, but it also works as a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into simillar issue, after couple of days investigating I've found in my case that I am requesting token with built in scopes (openid and profile) and without any custom scope which results in issuing tokens with different audiance (MS Graph) and hence tokens signed with with different public key (because I think that issued access_token is just a forward of the delegated MS Graph scope).

I resolved the issue by adding a custom scope in my app registration (Expose API section) and now my access_tokens are issued with valid audiance and I am able to check signature with my app public key.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the `audience` claim is used to point to the `client_id` of the client application you have registered in Azure/Microsoft. Looks to me that the error is occurring due to a mismatch of claims in `jwt`(probably audience). Check whether you have set the correct `client_id` for the audience variable.

Comment: This suggestion make sense and I have tried that too without success. Looking into the debugger I confirmed. PyJWT validates RSA signature before anything else. This is a fail in RSA signature validation step.

Comment: Did you try creating public key using the modulus `n` and exponent `e` values rather than using the `x5c web signature`.?

Comment: I did a implementation based on [this blog post](https://robertoprevato.github.io/Validating-JWT-Bearer-tokens-from-Azure-AD-in-Python/) that uses modules and exponent that you can find here: https://gist.github.com/tmpapageorgiou/0c1188283f5ee450b517ffe2f8912c98

Comment: @Thiago did you figure this out? I am experiencing the same issue as well.

Comment: @BrandonSmith Unfortunately I have not yet. I'm still looking into it, though. I will definitely post here if I figure it out.

Comment: @Thiago Any updates I am getting the same error and when trying to check my access_token on jwt.io I get also the same error but if I try to validate my Id_token it gets validated I am going mad and can't find any good documentation on that ... please share if you've found a solution

Comment: @zakibenz What I have found so far is that their JWT signature does not always follow the standards. It depends on how the access token was created.
Our application create this token with a resource different than the ClientID on azure. We actually changed that because of a different reason, so I can say we were lucky. Not sure if you can change the token creation, but once we create it withResource parameter to ClientID, the regular validation worked.
What your resource key has on the JWT json?

Comment: @Thiago I have no resource in my JWT ?!